# How do I use a custom icon for my Flash app?

Tags: flash, macromedia

when I publish my game, hoow do I make it so that that game alone hhas it's custom icon, instead of the default icon as always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a resource editor to replace the existing icon. Such as [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).